# How do I get forwarded to a link that is in a data attribute in html when clicked using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to forward to a link when the div is clicked using a data attribute and jQuery, but am stuck a bit. Here is the code I have:

html:

```
<div class="clickable-icon" data-link="www.google.com">click to be forwarded</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.clickable-icon').attr('data-link');
```

used google as an example for the link to go to. But how would I use jquery to help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do:

```
window.location.href = $('.clickable-icon').data('link');
```

and as you want on click, write click event and get clicked element **data-link** attribute value:

```
$('.clickable-icon').click(function () {

    window.location.href = $(this).data('link');

})
```

### [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jLjve5uj/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.location.href like

```
$('.clickable-icon').on('click', function() {
      window.location.href = $(this).data('link');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clickable-icon').click(function(){
    window.location.href = 'http://'+$(this).data('link');
})
```